# How come I lose the game when all hosts die, even if I have the Necrosis upgrade?

Tags: plague-inc, plague-inc-evolved

In Plague Inc, you can lose if all the hosts of your disease die. But the Necrosis upgrade allows people to get the disease from corpses. So if everyone with the disease dies while I have the Necrosis upgrade, shouldn't the game continue since I can still transmit the disease?

Comment: It's not supposed to be hyper realistic. People don't procreate or die of old age either.

Comment: Quarantines, probably? If you wouldn't be able to lose when all hosts die, you wouldn't be able to lose at all. As soon as you'd get the necrosis upgrade, you could just let the game idle until everyone is dead.

Comment: There are several ways people get rid of the bodies as well. Then your plague won't spread either.

Answer (score 3):

It's kinda just game logic, a punishment for over evolving your disease. Really the only way to explain this is if they burned bodies or quarantined people.